# Adding ' to string sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I got this code, the outcome of it is:

```
9316C747-76F7-4F3C-B35F-8E4CC96E214D,
232009BF-9867-4A5C-BD83-E41F1398ECA8,
68C15098-521F-4BE8-817B-26E73662E4EC,
F1F38030-632B-4756-A3B7-C7702D3BAA08,
D13947E5-E1BB-42CD-A5F8-02A9C0830979,
6BA64EE9-8D64-4545-A8D6-3E8A1DD33877,
DBA27DB9-FDE3-432B-B713-6801A3D01CA2
```

I'm interested in getting a list look like this:

```
'D91A4FE8-663A-4DDF-B6DB-95145DAD270B',
'8B30CBCC-8093-42A5-A1C8-FE88DFB7640F',
'A5E3202D-804C-477E-B54F-B80E72E871D9',
'5CE13B9B-9D31-4A03-9C5C-19B1C6D5915F',
'DB3447BC-2A89-4D8C-A865-6EB424D0EDA0',
'E7C0AB31-DA72-4456-971D-95881EC6B7F7',
'DDDECF74-7192-4B5F-91D6-ADF8756FFBFF',
'AF3D30C3-7233-4146-9BA0-13FB03B3BF13'
```

How is it possible to do this?

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' , '') + cast(int_guid as varchar(max)) 
FROM ex_in
SELECT @listStr
```

Comment: What is the code that generates the original result? It would probably be easier to alter that to get the final result.

Comment: Posted at the bottom

Comment: Did you try adding a `'` into that code?

Comment: Ofcourse but doesnt work out for me, ive tried " ' " and ' ' '

Comment: You should include your attempts to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add extra quotes. Try this.

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+''',''' , '') + cast(int_guid as varchar(max)) 
FROM ex_in
SELECT '''' + @listStr+''''
```

**Sample Demo**

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @str = Isnull(@str+''',''', '') + a
FROM   (SELECT '9316C747-76F7-4F3C-B35F-8E4CC96E214D' a
        UNION
        SELECT '232009BF-9867-4A5C-BD83-E41F1398ECA8'
        UNION
        SELECT '68C15098-521F-4BE8-817B-26E73662E4EC')dd

PRINT '''' + @str + ''''
```

Comment: Well then it would kinda lose the point. The point of it all is that i get a database table with status codes that went wrong. I want to make a commaseperated list with ' so that it automaticly can try send them through again. I dont want to add the code manually, and the strings will differ from time to time

Comment: @user3209714 - That is just a sample demo. Updated check now

Comment: it sourounde all the strings with '' but not each one    My bad i wasnt paying attention on what u did in the top. Great! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @listStr = @listStr + ',' + '''' + CAST(int_guid AS varchar(max)) + ''''
FROM ex_in

SET @listStr = STUFF(@listStr, 1, 1, '')
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79f82/2)